# Using the Rank Function

Tags: set-theory

I'm currently reading about the rank function in Kunen's set theory textbook, but I'm having some trouble using it. I've been following the proofs and examples with no issues. There is one problem that I'm stuck on. In this problem, they assume that every element of the reals $\mathbb{R}$, has rank $\omega$. They also consider the Lebesgue measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$, which I am not too familiar with. Here's the problem:

> Show both $\mathbb{R}$, $\mu \in WF$, with rank$(\mathbb{R}) = \omega + 1$ and rank$(\mu) = \omega + 4$.

$WF$ is the class of all well-founded sets, and for a relation $R$ on a class $A$ with $a,b \in A$, rank$(b) = \sup\{\mbox{rank}(a) + 1 : aRb \}.$

Here's what I was thinking so far: Since they assume every element of $\mathbb{R}$ has rank $\omega$, then for any $a, b \in WF$, rank$(b) = \sup\{\mbox{rank}(a) + 1 : aRb \} = \omega + 1$, meaning rank$(\mathbb{R}) = \omega + 1$.

For $\mu$, they give a hint: $\mu$ is a function with ran$(\mu) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\{\emptyset\} \subsetneq \mbox{dom}(\mu) \subset \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. I'm thinking $\mu \in WF$ follows from the hint if $\mathbb{R} \in WF$, but how would $\mathbb{R} \in WF$?

I was wondering if anyone could help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $R$ in the case of $\mathbb R$? The rank is not based on an arbitrary (well-founded) relation, but on membership. Also, you were just told that all elements of $\mathbb R$ have rank $\omega$, how come you then immediately say that $b$, an element of $\mathbb R$, has rank $\omega+1$, and further use that (how?) to conclude that the same is true of $\mathbb R$ itself?

Comment: I not sure what $R$ would be when looking at $\mathbb{R}$. $\in$ is well-founded on $WF$, so maybe $\in$? For the rank question, I wasn't sure if my reasoning was correct. I was thinking since that was the rank for an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{R}$, then it is the rank for all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The relevant (for this question) knowledge about $\mu$ is just that it's a function from a certain subset of $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Andres: $b$ is not an element of $\mathbb R$ here; it is the set we want the rank of, that is, $\mathbb R$ itself. So of course the rank of $\mathbb R$ is the rank of $b$ because $b=\mathbb R$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Read what Maria wrote: "for any $a,b\in\mathbb R$, $\mathrm{rank}(b)=\dots$"

Comment: @Maria The relevant rank here is with respect to $\in$. No element of $\mathbb R$ is an element of another element of $\mathbb R$, because they all have the same rank, which is $\omega$ instead of $\omega+1$. If $X$ is a set, and all its elements have the same rank, that is *not* the rank of $X$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Kunen usually refers to sets using lower-case letters, so as Henning mentioned, I think $b$ is a set.

Comment: @Maria: I think what Andres is saying here is that you should not have written "for any $a,b\in \mathbb R$", but "for any $b\in WF$".

Comment: @HenningMakholm I see what you mean. I will fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}$You have $\rank(\Bbb R)=\omega+1$. To get $\rank(\mu)$, work up to it.

- If $\varnothing\ne A\subseteq\Bbb R$, what is $\rank(A)$? What is $\rank\big(\{A\}\big)$? What about $\rank\big(\{A,x\}\big)$ if $x\in\Bbb R$?
- What is $\rank\big(\langle A,x\rangle\big)$ if $\varnothing\ne A\subseteq\Bbb R$ and $x\in\Bbb R$?
- What is $\rank(\mu)$?

Comment: Would rank$(A) = \omega + 1$? If that's the case, then by a Lemma in the text, rank$(\{A\}) = \omega +1 + 1 = \omega + 2$. Also, rank$( \{A, x\}) =$ max$( \mbox{rank}(A), \mbox{rank}(x)) + 1 = \omega + 1 + 1 = \omega + 2$ and rank$( \langle A, x\rangle) =$ max$( \mbox{rank}(A), \mbox{rank}(x)) + 2 = \omega + 1 + 2 = \omega + 3$. How would rank$(\mu) \ \omega + 4$ follow? I guess it would somehow use $\omega + 3 + 1$, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Giving it more thought, since  $\mu$ is a function from a certain subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then we are considering certain sets of $\{ \langle A, x \rangle \}$, meaning that the rank of $\mu$ will be $\omega + 3 + 1 = \omega + 4$. Is this correct reasoning?

Comment: @Maria: Yes, you got the first set right. and $\mu$ is a set of ordered pairs $\langle A,x\rangle$, so its rank is $(\omega+3)+1=\omega+4$, as you say in the second comment.

Comment: Thanks for your help with that part of the question Brian. How would I go about showing $\mathbb{R}, \mu \in WF$?

Comment: @Maria: By definition every set with a rank is in **WF**. Remember $\rank(x)=\alpha$ iff $x\in R(\alpha+1)$, and $\mathbf{WF}=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathbf{ON}}R(\alpha)$.

Comment: The book defines $R(\alpha)$ after this exercise, so I wasn't sure if it was ``legal" to use it.

Comment: @Maria: How does it define **WF**? The usual definition is the one that I gave in the previous comment.

Comment: Brian: Here's the definition: "The set $b$ is a well-founded set iff $\in$ is well-founded on $trcl(b)$, in which case rank$(b)$ denotes rank$_{{b} \cup trcl(b), \in}(b)$. $WF$ denotes the class of all well-founded sets."

Comment: @Maria: Ah; that’s quite different from the way he does it in his $1980$ book and did it in his graduate courses in the $1970$s. However, if you’re given that the rank of a real is $\omega$, then presumably you know that each real is in **WF**, so that $\Bbb R$ is a subset of **WF**; just show that if $x$ is a set whose elements are all in **WF**, then $x$ is also well-founded.

Comment: Brian: Thanks for all the help! His new book differs in many ways from the previous version. He does mention in a lemma before the exercise that if $x, y \in WF$, then $\bigcup x \in WF$, and $x \cup y \in WF$. I'm thinking that might help.

Comment: @Maria: You’re welcome! They may not help directly, but looking at how they’re proved may help. (I really ought to get a copy of the new version, if only out of curiosity: Ken was a superb teacher, and it would be interesting to see what he decided to change.)